# Introductory pages don't inherit plain pagestyle definitions

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I'm compiling a report with custom headers and footers, using the `scrreprt` document class. I have redefined the headers and footers of the `plain` pagestyle through the `scrpage2` package, but the redefined style doesn't apply for the table of contents or anything before that (ref. the code below).

How do I make my redefined `plain` pagestyle apply to the entire document?

```
\documentclass[11pt,b5paper,twoside,openright,parskip=full,abstract=true,BCOR=0.5cm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,microtype}
\usepackage{parskip,titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\KOMAoptions{numbers=noendperiod}

\ihead[]{\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ofoot[]{}
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}[\color{black!60!white}]
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot:\enskip}



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\noindent \lipsum[1-2]
\end{abstract}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter*{Possibly another introductory chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\tableofcontents


\chapter{First chapter}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\lipsum [1-3]


\section{Text train}
\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should consider in switching to `scrlayer-scrpage`, the successor of `scrpage2`. It is downwards compatible and provides more fetures. `scrpag2` wil be declared as obsolete with KOMA-Script version 3.13.

Comment: @Speravir Thanks for that. I actually thought it was the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your preamble after loading `scrpage2`:

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```